# right align/pad numbers in bash

Tags: bash, formatting

What's the best way to pad numbers when printing output in bash, such that the numbers are right aligned down the screen. So this:

```
00364.txt with 28 words in 0m0.927s
00366.txt with 105 words in 0m2.422s
00367.txt with 168 words in 0m3.292s
00368.txt with 1515 words in 0m27.238
```

Should be printed like this:

```
00364.txt with   28 words in 0m0.927s
00366.txt with  105 words in 0m2.422s
00367.txt with  168 words in 0m3.292s
00368.txt with 1515 words in 0m27.238
```

I'm printing these out line by line from within a for loop. And I will know the upper bound on the number of words in a file (just not right now).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

For bash, use the `printf` command with alignment flags.

For example:

```
printf '..%7s..' 'hello'
```

Prints:

```
..  hello..
```

Now, use your discretion for your problem.

Comment: Wow, ok that was pretty easy. I should have just RTFM. I guess I just incorrectly assumed it would be harder than that in bash. Thanks!

Comment: To remove the hard-coded "7" and **calculate the padding automatically**, see my answer below.

Comment: The OP specifically asked for right-alignment. But you can also left-align rather than right-align with `printf '..%-7s..' 'hello'`.

Answer (score 27):

Here's a little bit clearer example:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 21 137 1517
do
    printf "...%5d ...\n" "$i"
done
```

Produces:

```
...   21 ...
...  137 ...
... 1517 ...
```

Comment: Also, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4410103/26428) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2951428/26428).

Comment: Dennis: thank you for taking the time to make a clear example, without getting the correct answer points.

Comment: To remove the hard-coded "5" and calculate the padding automatically, see my answer below.

Answer (score 12):

If you are interested in changing width dynamically, you can use printf's '%*s' feature

```
printf '%*s' 20 hello
```

which prints

```
               hello
```

Comment: "dynamically", well, this is shell so I don't see how that's different from `printf "%${count}d" hello`

Comment: This is the best answer here, because '%*s' takes into account the length of the string.  If you do `printf '%*s' $(tput cols) hello`, hello will be printed at the far edge of the terminal window.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a combination of answers above which removes the hard-coded string length of `5` characters:

```
VALUES=( 21 137 1517 2121567251672561 )
MAX=1

# Calculate the length of the longest item in VALUES
for i in "${VALUES[@]}"; do
  [ ${#i} -gt ${MAX} ] && MAX=${#i}
done

for i in "${VALUES[@]}"; do
  printf "... %*s ...\n" $MAX "$i"
done
```

Result:

```
...               21 ...
...              137 ...
...             1517 ...
... 2121567251672561 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to get the number to be formatted from output of another script and you wish to pipe this result to be right align, just utilize `xargs`:

```
ls -1 | wc -l | xargs printf "%7d"
```