# ksh + printf , print the line with stat gap

Tags: ksh

I need to print the following:

- need smart ways by printf to print this example

  param1 ............... value1
  param2 ............... value2
  param3 ............... value1
  param4 ............... value2

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in 1 2 3 4
do
   printf "param%d ................. value%d\n" $i $i 
done
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in ksh93. I don't know about earlier versions.

This will print the data in columns with up to `n` dots between them

```
n=10
printf "%s %s %s\n" $column1 $(
    printf '.%.0s' {1..$(($n - ${#column1}))}
) $column2
```

Here's a demonstration:

```
n=10; j=8
for i in a ab abc abcd; do
    printf "%s %s %3d\n" $i $(
        printf '.%.0s' {1..$((10 - ${#i}))}
    ) $((j++))
done
```

And the output:

```
a .........   8
ab ........   9
abc .......  10
abcd ......  11
```

A little more complicated and it will do magic tricks:

```
n=20
string="mnopqrstuvw"
strl=${#string}
k=0
for i in a ab abc abcd abcde abcd abc ab a
do
    j=${string: -$((strl-(k++)))}
    printf "%s %s %s\n" $i $(
        printf '.%.0s' {1..$((n - ${#i} - ${#j}))}
    ) $j
done
```

Output:

```
a ........ mnopqrstuvw
ab ........ nopqrstuvw
abc ........ opqrstuvw
abcd ........ pqrstuvw
abcde ........ qrstuvw
abcd .......... rstuvw
abc ............ stuvw
ab .............. tuvw
a ................ uvw
```