# How to print an already formatted String in Java

Tags: java, println, system.out

I have a paragraph which has been indented already. for example

```
Hello:
     Hi every body
```

Now I want to print this in Java. using `System.out.println` I have to put this function in each line. How can I do it like when you use print in python that you just put a " around it and it's already ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got one `String.format` method, that returns a `formatted` string: -

```
String str = String.format("%s%n%20s", "Hello", "Hi everyone!");
System.out.println(str);
```

`%n` in string formatting is used to print a `newline` character.

`%20s` will right indent the string, and will take `20` charater space.

---

If you want to print the formatted string, rather than storing it, you can use `System.out.format`: -

```
System.out.format("%s%n%20s", "Hello", "Hi everyone!");
```

Answer (score 4):

Formatting the string like this is one way:

```
"Hello:\n\tHi every body"
```

Comment: For those wo don't know it: `\n` is a new line, `\t` is a TAB. Good answer, upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use special characters like `\n` for new line.

```
System.out.println("Hello:\n     Hi everybody");
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you just use newline and tab escape sequences - `\t` and `\n`

Here's a simple example:

```
//Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped
import java.io.*;  

class Tabs {  
  public static void main(String[] args) {  
    try {  
      String t = "\t\t";  
      PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("tabs.txt");  
      ps.print("A" + t + "B");  
      ps.print("C\t\tD");  
    } catch(Exception e) {  
      System.err.println(e);  
    }  
  }  
}
```

[source](http://www.coderanch.com/t/511159/java/java/Printing-tab-characters)

Also see - [Printing with "\t" (tabs) does not result in aligned columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000810/printing-with-t-tabs-problem)

Play with it, you'll figure it out