# \t not consistent with spacing in Java

Tags: java, format

So I've used this:

```
System.out.println("Of what race do you belong?\n[H]uman\t [E]lf\t [D]warf\t [O]rc\t [G]nome");
```

And gotten a print with very random spacing where \t has been placed. I've also used this same type of thing with this:

```
System.out.println("Which of the following are you?\n[W]arrior\t [R]ogue\t [M]agician");
```

And gotten perfectly spaced breaks for the \t. Any reason why it would give me such odd spacing with the 1st one?

Comment: \t is a tab not a space.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000810/printing-with-t-tabs-problem

Comment: Try writing the same text in a notepad or anywhere and instead of writing `\t` press the TAB to see the output. Compare such output with the output of your application.

Comment: You don't need to combine `\t` with ` `.  I suggest you use printf("%12s", "text") or similar to control the spacing.

Comment: Your terminal determines how tab characters are displayed, not Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\t is tab. Open a regular text editor and check how a tab behaves. It indents to a certain position. It DOES NOT insert x number of spaces.

Comment: I should have realized this as it's very clear what tab does in notepad++. Thanks a ton for pointing out the obvious when I am oblivious.

Answer (score 2):

`\t` inserts a TAB character, not spaces. Knowing this, you **should not** use tabs to format the output of your data.

Since this looks for displaying data to user, it would be better using [`String#format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) which allows providing spaces to both left and right sides for your text.

Here's an example using `%-15s`:

```
//splitted in 2 lines for better understanding
String outputText = String.format("Of what race do you belong? %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s",
    "[H]uman", "[E]lf", "[D]warf", "[O]rc", "[G]nome");
System.out.println(outputText);
```

Where:

- `%s` means that it will add a `String` to the output.
- `15` is the number of spaces to locate the string
- `-` indicates it should be left aligned.

Output of code above:

```
Of what race do you belong? [H]uman         [E]lf           [D]warf         [O]rc           [G]nome
```

You can shorten the length of the spaces by just modifying the `-15`.

More info about how to proper format your output text:

- [`java.util.Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) class used behind the scenes when calling `String#format`.

Note that using `System.out.printf` uses `Formatter` behind the scene as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `\t` character is a tabulation character.

Subsequent tabs act "inconsistently", as in, they won't display the same amount of space.

You should use a regular number of spaces instead.

Something like:

```
System.out.println("Of what race do you belong?\n[H]uman   [E]lf   [D]warf   [O]rc   [G]nome");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `\t` you are adding a tab and not a space.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said \t is tab and a space is always one column but tab could be a different number of columns depending on your environment.