# Java tab in system out

Tags: java

I have to create an application where I will print the result of a student. In the assignment we have to use the `\t`, in order to tab everything in a good line.

```
   for(int i = 0; i< 7; i++) {
         System.out.println("Vak/Project :" + naamVak[i] + "\t\tCijfer: " +
      inputCijfer[i] + "\tBehaalde studiepunten: " + studiepuntenVAK[i]);
   }
```

It does print the name of the project (array called `naamVak`), the result (`inputCijfer`), and how many points they have got per project (`studiepuntenVak`).

When I print the results to the console, it shows as follows:

```
Vak/Project :Fasten Your Seatbelts      Cijfer: 1.0 Behaalde studiepunten: 0
Vak/Project :Programming        Cijfer: 2.0 Behaalde studiepunten: 0
Vak/Project :Databases      Cijfer: 3.0 Behaalde studiepunten: 0
Vak/Project :Personal Skills        Cijfer: 4.0 Behaalde studiepunten: 0
Vak/Project :Project Skills     Cijfer: 5.0 Behaalde studiepunten: 0
Vak/Project :Infrastructure     Cijfer: 6.0 Behaalde studiepunten: 3
Vak/Project :Network Engineering 1      Cijfer: 7.0 Behaalde studiepunten: 3
```

How can I create the output to be all in a correct line?

Comment: you could "calculate" the lenght of the already printed part, and start from there. /t doesn't take the previous or next lines into account

Comment: Have a look at the [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) methods.

Comment: [StringUtils#rightPad](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) might be helpful.

Comment: tabulator, even corrected in his counts, is not guaranted in all envinroments. Read about formatting, f.e. class java.util.Formatter and format in fixed length

Comment: tab usually is counted as every 8th character, but not always

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing with "\t" (tabs) does not result in aligned columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000810/printing-with-t-tabs-does-not-result-in-aligned-columns)

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.format method (with a printf like syntax), and provide a value for width. The syntax is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax , You could use like:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%20s %20s %20s", naamVak[i], inputCijfer[i], studiepuntenVAK[i]));
```

this assumes a max input width of 20 chars for each column

Comment: Thanks, really thanks! I will try this out when I get home. Will give you some feedback when Im done.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

You can use  String.format method

```
String s1 = String.format("test right alignment:  %13s   %50s  ",'test a short string', 'test a very very very long string' );
String s2 = String.format("test left  aligmnent:  %-13s   %-50s  ",'test a short string', 'test a very very very long string'  );

System.out.println(s1);
System.out.println(s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(String.format("%20s %20s %20s %20s %20s", "Vak/Project: ", naamVak[i], "Cijfer: ", inputCijfer[i], "Behaalde studiepunten: ", studiepuntenVAK[i]));
```

Still gives a strange view for the user. This is the output in console:

```
   Vak/Project:  Fasten Your Seatbelts             Cijfer:                   8.6 Behaalde studiepunten: 
   Vak/Project:           Programming             Cijfer:                   7.5 Behaalde studiepunten: 
   Vak/Project:             Databases             Cijfer:                   2.1 Behaalde studiepunten: 
   Vak/Project:       Personal Skills             Cijfer:                   2.3 Behaalde studiepunten: 
   Vak/Project:        Project Skills             Cijfer:                   2.4 Behaalde studiepunten: 
   Vak/Project:        Infrastructure             Cijfer:                   2.5 Behaalde studiepunten: 
   Vak/Project:  Network Engineering 1             Cijfer:                   2.6 Behaalde studiepunten:
```

Comment: You should not use answers as a way to exchange posts, but anyway, that is because the first and the last rows contain entries that are longer that 20 characters: "Fasten Your Seatbelts" and "Network Engineering 1". You can for example adjust the "%20s %20s %20s %20s %20s" to like "%20s %30s %20s %20s %20s" or something