# How to indent in Java using format

Tags: java

I am looking to indent a print line in Java using format but I'm a little confused by the process.

I searched around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000810/printing-with-t-tabs-does-not-result-in-aligned-columns#20873713) which presents the following option:

```
String prefix1 = "short text:";
String prefix2 = "looooooooooooooong text:";
String msg = "indented";
/*
 * The second string begins after 40 characters. The dash means that the
 * first string is left-justified.
 */
String format = "%-40s%s%n";
System.out.printf(format, prefix1, msg);
System.out.printf(format, prefix2, msg);
```

I implemented it in my own code in the following way:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Take in user input for report title
        System.out.println("Enter a title for this report");

        String msg = "=> ";
        String blank = "";

        String format = "%-4s%s%n";
        System.out.printf(format, blank, msg);
    }
}
```

I tried removing the blank with the following:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Take in user input for report title
        System.out.println("Enter a title for this report");

        String msg = "=> ";

        String format = "%-4s%s%n";
        System.out.printf(format, msg);
    }
}
```

But I receive the following error in IntelliJ IDEA:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException:
> Format specifier '%s'     at
> java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2672)     at
> java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1053)   at
> java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:949)    at
> Main.main(Main.java:32)

My question is, why is that first string required? Is there a way to do it without declaring the "blank" variable I have? I apologize if this is answered somewhere, I searched but could not find it.

This is my desired output:

```
Enter a title for this report
    =>
```

Comment: What is your desired output? Please edit your question to include that. As for "why", every `%s` is a placeholder for a `String`. If you have two `%s`(s) then you need two `String`(s).

Comment: change to `System.out.printf(format, msg, "some string");` to supply 2 strings to match 2 `%s` in your `format`

Comment: You only need to have as many '%s' specifiiers as the string you're specifyint to fomrat. So if you want to remove the blank variable's dependency, remove one %s. from the format.

Comment: Or you could just use a `tab` `String format = "\t%s%n";`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch edited my post to include my desired output.

Comment: @Kartik I tried the following and it's not indenting the line.

String format = "%-4s";

        System.out.println("Enter a title for this report");

        System.out.printf(format, "=> ");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change your format string:

```
String format = "%8s%n";
```

Remove one `%s` as you are passing one less string compared to your example code and `8` is the indent for your second line.

Use the value `8` because `1 tab = 8 spaces`.

Answer (score 1):

This may work.

```
import java.util.Formatter;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter a title for this report");
    String msg = "=>";
    String output = String.format("%6s\n",msg); //7 th line
    System.out.print(output);

    }
}
```

In the 7th line I have specified (6s) means total string will be of length 6. **msg** is length of 2 then remaining 4 spaces will be assigned to left(if we mention "-6" 4spaces will be assigned to right) to the string **msg**