# How tab works in Java?

Tags: java, tabs

I came across a weired situation while using tabs. Mostly tabs are made up of 8 or 4 spaces. But lets say right now its 8

For example

```
"abc"+"\t"+"bcd"      -> abc        bcd
"abcderft"+"\t"+"bcd" -> abcderft   bcd
```

Why am getting differences in `tab distance` between two strings ?

Checked this post too

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000810/printing-with-t-tabs-does-not-result-in-aligned-columns
```

Didnt clear much.

Even if tab is equivalent to 8 spaces, then why its considering the string count ? I mean if my string length is 3 then next string am getting after only 5 spaces, and if string length is 8 then next string is coming after 8 characters.

Does tabs includes the string length too post which its being added ?

Comment: Tabs don't do anything in Java. They are just characters. The way they are printed is a function of your terminal.

Comment: @AndyTurner, if I do string1+"\t"+string, Will it consider it as a whole string or strings seperated by tab ?

Comment: Maria, when you concatenate strimgs the result of that expression is a new "whole" string.

Comment: @Stefan, Any way I could treat them as a tab delimited string ?

Comment: You can split strings at tab characters using ```String[] parts=yourString.split("\t")```. If that is not what you want, then please be more specific what input you have and what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Tabs are made to align text in columns.
So yes they are multiple spaces from an empty start of the line, but not anymore following some text, as they'll go to say the next columns multiple of 8 (or 4).
So as you guessed, they include part of the length of he text before them

Comment: so "\t" is kind of padding to complete the string of 8 character ?

Comment: yes! Knowing it will also make it grow to 16 if it was already exactly 8 long