# How to output numbered columns vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: bash, multiple-columns

The following script lists items in a directory. It produces an output of 3 numbered columns. The numbered output is listed horizontally from left to right across the columns. I would instead like the output to be listed vertically down the first column, then the second, and then the third. How do I accomplish this?

**The script**

```
#!/bin/bash

menu=( $(ls ${HOME}) )
i=0
for m in ${menu[@]}
do 
    echo "$(( i++ ))) ${m}"
done | xargs -L3 | column -t
```

**The output**

```
0)   item    1)   item   2)   item
3)   item    4)   item   5)   item
6)   item    7)   item   8)   item
9)   item    10)  item   11)  item
12)  item    13)  item   14)  item
```

**The desired output**

```
0)  item    5)  item    10)  item
1)  item    6)  item    11)  item
2)  item    7)  item    12)  item
3)  item    8)  item    13)  item
4)  item    9)  item    14)  item
```

Comment: Please see if this helps, looks you need padding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409399/padding-characters-in-printf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without rewriting your code too much, this will work:

```
#!/bin/bash

menu=( $(ls ${HOME}) )
totalRows=$(( ${#menu[*]} / 3 + 1 ))
i=0
for m in ${menu[@]}
do    
    echo "$(( i/3 + (i%3)*totalRows ))) ${m}"
    let i++
done | xargs -L3 | column -t
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try something like this;

```
#!/bin/bash
menu=( ${HOME}/* )
menLen=${#menu[@]}
rowCounts=$(echo $(( $menLen / 3 )))
for (( c=0; c<$rowCounts; c++ ))
do
findex=$c;
sindex=$(echo $(( $findex + $rowCounts )))
tindex=$(echo $(( $sindex + $rowCounts )))
printf "%-40s \t %-40s \t %-40s \n" "$findex ) ${menu[$findex]##*/}" "$sindex ) ${menu[$sindex]##*/}" "$tindex ) ${menu[$tindex]##*/}"
done
```