# Create dynamic table in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have bash script which creates different users and password. The passwords and users are stored in variables.

```
    cat << EOT
+---------------------------------------+
| Linux Logins                          |
+---------------+-----------------------+
| User          | Password              |
+---------------+-----------------------+
| $test      | $testpw               |
+---------------+-----------------------+

EOT
```

The Problem with this is that depending on the length of the stored variables the table gets messed up like this:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Linux Logins                          |
+---------------+-----------------------+
| User          | Password              |
+---------------+-----------------------+
| michael         | helolopk8712t76               |
+---------------+-----------------------+
```

This is because the tabs are hardcoded. How can I solve this in a different way? I know there is awk and column to do so.
I want it dynamic as in mysql console if that is possible.

Comment: I believe this is not possible with here docs. Probably the way to go is using `printf` as described in [Padding characters in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4409399/1983854)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean to say that your problem is due to the fact that your tabs are *not* hardcoded.  But tabs are not really flexible enough to do what you want.  You could do:

```
cat << EOT            
+---------------------------------------+              
| Linux Logins                          |              
+---------------+-----------------------+              
| User          | Password              |              
+---------------+-----------------------+              
| $(printf %-14s "$test")| $(printf %-22s "$testpw")|          
+---------------+-----------------------+              

EOT
```

Comment: @patrick_  Sorry, I had cut-n-pasted from a function and was using `$1` and `$2` instead of `$test` and `$testpw`.  I should have left the original answer with the function definition!

Comment: Thanks this seems to work with passwords up to 22 chars. More than 22 chars is not realistic so this solution works perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: could also be done with `printf -v` which is more efficient because avoids to call a subshell an to pipe result in expansion

Answer (score 1):

variables can be padded with printf

```
printf -v test   %20s "$test"
printf -v testpw %20s "$testpw"
```

or for left align

```
printf -v test   %-20s "$test"
printf -v testpw %-20s "$testpw"
```

or to trunc after a specific length (19)

```
printf -v test   %-20.19s "$test"
printf -v testpw %-20.19s "$testpw"
```

Answer (score 0):

Great answers. If it's of use to anyone, my table assigns colours and right-aligns the values. To use: create a file e.g. `table.sh`, set the permissions `chmod u+x table.sh` and run the file `./table.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Define colours
CYAN='\033[0;36m' 
GREEN='\033[0;32m' 
LIGHTRED='\033[1;31m' 
MAGENTA='\033[1;35m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Colour 
YELLOW='\033[1;33m' 

# Hard code variable values for this POC 
critical=0
high=2
medium=12
low=112
notScanned=10
total=136

# Print table with values right-aligned & colour-coded 

echo
printf "${NC}+--------------------------------+\n"
printf "${NC}|  ECR Vulnerabilities           |\n"
printf "${NC}+--------------------------------+\n"
printf "${NC}|  Critical      |${LIGHTRED} $(printf '%8.5s\n' ${critical})${NC}      |\n"
printf "${NC}+--------------------------------+\n"
printf "${NC}|  High          |${MAGENTA} $(printf '%8.5s\n' ${high})${NC}      |\n"
printf "${NC}+--------------------------------+\n"
printf "${NC}|  Medium        |${YELLOW} $(printf '%8.5s\n' ${medium})${NC}      |\n"
printf "${NC}+--------------------------------+\n"
printf "${NC}|  Low           |${CYAN} $(printf '%8.5s\n' ${low})${NC}      |\n"
printf "${NC}+--------------------------------+\n"
printf "${NC}|  Not Scanned   |${NC} $(printf '%8.5s\n' ${notScanned})${NC}      |\n"
printf "${NC}+--------------------------------+\n"
printf "${NC}|  Total         |${GREEN} $(printf '%8.5s\n' ${total})${NC}      |\n"
printf "${NC}+--------------------------------+\n"
```