# Pad a string to a certain length with a chosen character (or hexcode) in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to pad a string in Bash to a certain length with any chosen character (or hexcode).

Suppose I have the string `AABB` and want to pad it using `X` or (`0x00`) to length 10:

`AABBXXXXXX`

I know how to pad with spaces using `printf`. How can I pad with an arbitrary character (or hexcode)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Padding characters in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409399/padding-characters-in-printf)

Comment: @Igor: Though it looks obvious, it is not a dupe, the OP's requirement here, cannot be done directly with `printf`

Comment: @Inian What happend to you answer? I considered it to be the most fitting answer.

Comment: @Socowi: Thanks! but from my now deleted answer, OP's comment was _What I mean by hex it to insert a null byte or 0x0a - not the character, but the binary itself_  -- meaning OP wants a byte sequence to be appended to a binary file which was totally contradicting my original answer.

Comment: @Inian Ok, I wouldn't have guessed that from OP's question.

Comment: @Inian your answer was fine - I asked two questions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### For strings without spaces

Use `printf` to pad with spaces, then replace the spaces with a symbol of your choice. Some examples:

`printf %10s AABB | tr ' ' X` prints `XXXXXXAABB`.
`printf %-10s AABB | tr ' ' X` prints `AABBXXXXXX`.

To insert non-printable symbols instead of `X`, you can pass an octal escape sequence to `tr`. `printf` can convert hexadecimal numbers into octal ones:

`printf %10s AABB | tr ' ' \\$(printf %o 0x1f)` prints the bytes `1f 1f 1f 1f 1f 1f 41 41 42 42` (can be confirmed by piping through `od -tx1 -An`).

#### For strings with spaces

```
str=AABB
yes "" | head -n $((10-"${#str}")) | tr \\n X
printf %s "$str"
```

Swap the last two lines to insert padding at the right (like `%-10s`). Just like before, you can replace `X` with `\\$(printf %o 0x1f)` to insert non-printable characters.

Answer (score 4):

Solutions using loops:

```
str=AABB
while ((${#str} < 10)); do 
  str+='X'
done
echo $str
```

```
str=AABB
for ((i=${#str};i<10;++i)); do 
  str+='X'
done
echo $str
```

However you can't add null byte to a string in bash. My bash issues a warning:

```
bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input
```

In that case, we need to operate on files, maybe like this:

```
echo -n AABB >/tmp/1
while (($(wc -c </tmp/1) < 10)); do 
   echo -ne '\x00' >> /tmp/1
done
cat /tmp/1 | hexdump -C
00000000  41 41 42 42 00 00 00 00  00 00                    |AABB......|
0000000a
```

Answer (score 0):

I was inspired by @Socowi's answer and wanted to improve on it!

pad right:

```bash
str=123456
echo $str$(printf -- x%.s $(seq -s ' ' $((10-${#str}))))
#                    ↑                    ↑↑
#                 padding               length
# output: 123456xxxx
```

pad left:

```bash
str=123456
echo $(printf -- x%.s $(seq -s ' ' $((10-${#str}))))$str
#                ↑                    ↑↑
#             padding               length
# output: xxxx123456
```