# Bash read text file and print out each line padded to a certain length

Tags: bash, printf, git-bash

I have a datafile (data.txt) with column names need to pad them with dash '-' to the length of a variable (string_limit). I have found a lot of bash examples using printf, but none of them print out the expected results

edit: the problem is with Git Bash on windows. I tested the examples printed out expected results on ubuntu 20, but not on Git Bash

```
colA
coluB
columC
```

output:

```
colA----------
coluB---------
columC--------
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Padding characters in printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409399/padding-characters-in-printf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### What I would do:

```
#!/bin/bash

padding=12
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf -v str '%s%*s' "$line" $((padding-${#line})) ' '
    printf '%s\n' "${str// /-}"
done < file
```

##### Output

```
colA--------
coluB-------
columC------
```

Comment: thanks! it work on Ubuntu. but on windows bash, it printed empty strings
$ ./pad.sh 
-------
------

Comment: Can you share your script ? https://bpa.st/ Is it in PowerShell, git-bash, cmd? Anything else? (WSL). And how you run the script?

Comment: Looks like my edit resolved the issue? If yes, thanks to edit your original post to remove the git bash part and clean comment here