# Unexpected padding behavior with printf

Tags: bash, formatting

I'm trying to pad spaces onto a series of strings in bash, using the `printf` suggestions outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994461/right-align-pad-numbers-in-bash/994471#994471) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994461/right-align-pad-numbers-in-bash/994953#994953).

Iterating over test characters...

```
for i in a b c d e f g
do
  printf "%-7s" "$i"
done
```

...produces expected results:

```
a      b      c      d      e      f      g
```

But iterating over the actual strings produces strange results:

```
for i in date sha percent total covered uncovered
do
  printf "%-7s" "$i"
done

date   sha    percenttotal  covereduncovered
```

Why do those two iterations result in different spacing?

Comment: The shell's `printf` command has the useful feature of *repeating* tbe format until it runs out of arguments. So you don't need the`for` loop. You can just do `printf '%-7s' date sha percent total covered uncovered`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding only adds spaces to bring the total width up to 7. `percent` and `covered`, though, already *have* 7 characters, so no padding is necessary after either string.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
$ for i in date sha percent total covered uncovered; do
>   printf "%-7s%-6s" "$i" ""
> done
date         sha          percent      total        covered      uncovered      $
```

(Notice that my prompt is at the end of that string.)