# Special print in bash

Tags: bash

I would like to print data format like this in bash shell. Can you suggest how to print the numbers out?

```
Number=     1
Number=    10
Number=   100
Number=  1000
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [right align/pad numbers in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994461/right-align-pad-numbers-in-bash) (see the second answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/994953/1773798)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `printf`; it allows format strings, including padding:

```
for n in 1 10 100 1000; do
    printf "Number=%6s\n" $n
done
```

```
Number=     1
Number=    10
Number=   100
Number=  1000
```